# Angular Property Binding with Condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can I add a `+ 1` to my condition with `[class.active]` binding? It isn't working in this way...

```
[class.active]="userProfile.id === (userProfile.lastId + 1)"
```

Comment: How is it not working? It looks fine.

Comment: use ngClass instead

Comment: there is no way to help you without knowing more about userProfile.id and userProfile.lastId data types.

Comment: @D Pro Datatype is both number

Comment: @aosh5 check if your property looks like `id:1` instead of `id:'1'` Also can you please console.log(userProfile) object and post output here

Answer (score 0):

Use `userProfile['lastId']  + 1`

Try:

```
[class.active]="userProfile.id === userProfile['lastId']  + 1)"
```

Comment: I think should be inside of quote `'lastId'`

Comment: from where it will get `lastId`?i think you wanna say `userProfile['lastId']+1`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine check stackblitz example below or you can use `ngClass`

```
[ngClass]="{'active': userProfile.id == (userProfile.lastId + 1)}"
```

**Check if peroperties that you'r using are of number typo may be they are evaluating to string like id:'1'**

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3twqtk)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[ngClass]="{'active': userProfile.id === userProfile.lastId + 1}"
```

Comment: What's the point of changing `[class.active]=` to `[ngClass]=` here?

Comment: @mbojko nothing I think ,this the same as the questions 

Answer (score 0):

you can uns `==` if any of the proprty are not number (string value) , drop the type checking

```
<p [class.active]="+userProfile.id == (+userProfile.lastId + 1)" >...</p>
```

> the `+` infornt of `userProfile.lastId,userProfile.id` will convert the value to number